# Combining data from two tables into one

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

I have three datagridviews as shown in the images.  Well I did have but had to remove them.

The SQL selection for the Income Received datagridview is as follows:

```
("Select I_Stock_Code as 'Stock Code', Income_Date, Dividend_Amount as 'Dividend Income',  Franked_Income as 'Franking Credit Income', Option_Income as 'Option Income', Dividend_Amount + Option_Income + Franked_Income  as 'Total Income', Notes from Income order by I_Stock_Code",  JKPLConnection);
```

The SQL selection for the Detailed Investments datagridview is as follows:

```
("Select B_Stock_Code as 'Stock Code', Buy_Date, Number_Bought as 'Bought',Price as 'Buy Price', Brokerage as '  Brokerage Cost', Total_Cost as 'Investment Cost', Interest_Rate as 'Opportunity Interest Rate %',  Acc_interest as 'Accumulated Interest', (Total_Cost + Acc_Interest)/Number_Bought as 'Breakeven Price'FROM Buy  ORDER BY B_Stock_Code", JKPLConnection);
```

The SQL selection for the Consolidated Investment datagridview is as follows:

```
("SELECT B_Stock_Code as 'Stock Code', COUNT (Number_Bought) as Transactions, SUM (Number_Bought) AS Bought, SUM (Total_Cost)/SUM (Number_Bought) AS  'Average Buy Price', SUM (Total_Cost) AS 'Total Investment', SUM (ACC_Interest) AS 'Opportunity Interest Cost', (SUM (Total_Cost) + SUM(ACC_Interest))/SUM (Number_Bought) AS 'Breakeven Price' FROM buy GROUP BY B_Stock_Code", JKPLConnection);
```

I am happy with this so far.  My problem is that I want to get into the Consolidated Investment datagridview a column showing the income generated from each investment.

In order to test my SQL commands I have used a separate program to test the statements before trying to integrate them into the program that has produced the three datagridviews My best effort is shown in the SQL Tester image.  As can be seen the number bought for BHP is duplicated over and over again; Column1 that shows income provides figures that are completely wrong.  ![SQL Tester][4]
I am at a total loss as to a solution.  This is the code that generated  the view.

```
SELECT 
    Buy.B_Stock_Code AS StockCode,  
    SUM(buy.Number_Bought) AS NumberBought,
    SUM(Buy.Total_Cost) AS TotalCost, 
    SUM(Buy.Acc_Interest + Buy.Total_Cost) AS TotalInvestment, 
    SUM(Income.Option_Income + Income.Franked_Income + Income.Option_Income)
FROM 
    Buy
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    Income ON Buy.B_Stock_Code = Income.I_Stock_Code
GROUP BY 
    Buy.B_Stock_Code, Income.Incomeid
ORDER BY 
    B_Stock_Code
```

I am using C# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop. I hope this is not too much information but more importantly that it conveys my problem clearly. I have had to delete the images because I was not allowed to upload them.  If anyone can shed light on this and the info above is not sufficient I would be happy to email the images.

Comment: You can use the _code_-button `{}` in the editor to format code blocks like sql queries.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: use proper code format to make your question readable.

Comment: can you please provide your expected result in your question too?

Comment: Can you please upload your images on fliker and mentioned the links in your question?

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback. I have since discovered that the error is caused by use of “GROUP BY”   related to the summing of rows in the SQL JOIN query. Since I hope to be able to explain this better now and hopefully use the right format, I have added a new post.